# Java regex: why numbers [0-9], comma etc. is not an unicode?

Tags: java, regex, unicode

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String regex = "\\p{L}";
        System.out.println("0".matches(regex));
    }
}
```

The code above prints false, but I was expecting true because **isn't ASCII a subset of unicode**? "0" is part of ASCII, so I think it should also belongs to a unicode letter.

Also, comma, period etc prints "false" true, while "a" will print true.

Comment: I wonder if the "L" stands for "letter" ... what do you think? Since it accepts letters, but no digits ... And yet again, no research earns an upvote ... lovely.

Comment: If you plan to match Unicode letters and all ASCII symbols, use `"[\\p{L}\\p{ASCII}]"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because `\\p{L}` matches a Unicode letter and you're matching a digit.

You can use:

```
[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}.,]
```

to match a Unicode digit or letter.

You should also use `(?U)` in front of your regex for Unicode support like this:

```
String regex = "(?U)[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}.,]+";
```

Comment: Thanks! \\p{N} works for digits. But for comma (i.e. ",") what should I use then?

Comment: Why would you add `(?U)` ([UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS))? `\p{L}` and `\p{Nd}` are already full unicode, and are unaffected by `(?U)`. As the javadoc says: *"Enables the Unicode version of Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes"*, e.g. `\w` (predefined) and `\p{Alpha}` (POSIX).

Comment: Yes your are right @Andreas. There is no need to use `(?U)` for `\p{L}` and `\p{Nd}`. But I wasn't too sure about unicode variants of `dot` and comma so suggested to use it.